# как прокинуть порт mysql из docker контейнера

Tags: mysql, docker

Делаю так

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -v /Project/src:/var/www/html -v /Project/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 -p 127.0.0.1:8000:3306 c5f27f3ba5ac
```

базу настраивал так

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql ]; then
    # Выставляем правильные права доступа
    chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

    # Инициализируем системные таблицы
    mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql
    service mysql restart
fi
usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
echo "bind-address=0.0.0.0" >> /etc/mysql/my.cfg
chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld
service mysql start
```

В докер файле так

```
ENTRYPOINT  /start.sh && service mysql start
```

Пробую конектится на localhost:8000
хотя apache2  пробросился на 8080 и тестовая страничка открывается

Дописал

```
usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
mysqld_safe --bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

`--bind-address=0.0.0.0` - Нужно чтобы был доступ из вне

Настраивал практически по этой статье https://blog.amartynov.ru/docker-mysql/

В общем я в docker поставил ssh  и подключаюсь через тунель, так и живу =(

Comment: Из этого описания абсолютно непонятно, что у вас в контейнере, но ошибка довольно ясно говорит "A mysqld process already exists".  Проверьте наличие работающего процесса mysql и процесса с идентификатором из pid-файла

Comment: Ошибки сейчас нет, я захожу в контейнере в mysql создаю базу, могу в общем работать, а из системы не могу подключиться к mysql через phpstorm или vstudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Presentasion <example@google.com>

RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql

RUN apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qqy install git \
    php7.0-cli php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-imap php7.0-intl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-soap \
    php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-xml php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath \
    php-xdebug apache2 libapache2-mod-php ssh nano htop net-tools\
    && apt-get -y upgrade \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get -y clean 

#install composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
    && composer clear-cache 

# Adding mysql-server
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/mysql

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ADD start.sh /
RUN chmod +x /start.sh 

RUN sed -Ei 's/^(bind-address|log)/#&/' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf 

EXPOSE 3306

ENTRYPOINT  /start.sh \           
            && service apache2 start \
            && /bin/bash 
            #&& echo "Hit [enter] key or run 'docker stop <container>' to exit container" \
            #&& read USR_INPUT
```

И start.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql ]; then
    # Выставляем правильные права доступа
    chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

    # Инициализируем системные таблицы
    mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql
    service mysql start
    echo "GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'dev'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'dev' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0;" | mysql -uroot
    echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'dev'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;" | mysql -uroot
    echo "bind-address=0.0.0.0" >> /etc/mysql/my.cfg

    #/etc/init.d/mysql restart
fi
echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.remote_port="9000"' >> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.profiler_enable=1' >> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.profiler_output_dir="\tmp"' >> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1' >> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini

service mysql start
```